# Unity C# Dragged item positions itself a few centimeters above mouse mosition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a script (For drag and drop inventory system) that was working fine yesterday, but this morning the Items being dragged no longer followed the mouse pointer at the crusors position but instead followed it with a at a distance. So upon clicking the item, nothing happened, once i start dragging the item x,y values just changed and placed itself a few centimeters above the crusor whilst still following the crusor.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragHandler : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    public static GameObject itemBeingDragged;
    Vector2 startPosition;
    Transform startParent;
    

    public void OnBeginDrag ( PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        itemBeingDragged = gameObject;
        startPosition = transform.position;
        startParent = transform.parent;
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
    }
    public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }
    public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        itemBeingDragged = null;
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;
        if (transform.parent == startParent)
            {
                transform.position = startPosition;  
            }  
    }
}  
´´´
```

Comment: Please ensure you are using correct tags. This question is not about [tag:unityscript], but it **is** about [tag:unity3d].

Answer (score -1):

When you drag an item, the mouse can be anywhere inside the item. You should therefore calculate the delta between the mouse position and the position of the dragged item. You can then add this delta in the OnDrag() functions when setting a new position.

```
Vector3 delta;

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    itemBeingDragged = gameObject;
    delta = itemBeingDragged.transform.position - 
        new Vector3(eventData.pressPosition.x, eventData.pressPosition.y, 0);
    // ....
}

... 

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    transform.position = Input.mousePosition + delta;
}
```

Note that we should not use the Input.mousePosition in the OnBeginDrag() since the drag operation starts first after the mouse has moved a bit. We could of course calculate the delta as soon as the mouse button was pressed, and then we can use the Input.mousePosition. But, since you use the OnBeginDrag() we use the event's pressPosition which is the mousePosition when pressed.

Comment: I would like to thank you for the detailed response and the time you put into this. 

I'll add the line and implement the suggested changes to the Script.